# Cannot make my div tag move down using margin-top?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to do here is give my username div a `margin-top:10%;`
simple as that.

[Here](http://projectarchive.sulmaxcp.com/login.php) is an example of what it currently looks like live  as you can see my username area is jammed right at the top of my content `div`.

All I wanted is to budge it down a tad. Any ideas on why or how to fix this?

**CODE**

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #222222;
}
#header {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  width: 60%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #303640;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#username {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #373e49;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #373e49;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#usernameIcon {
  width: 12%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.usernameIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#usernameTextbox {
  width: 88%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.tbUsername {
  background-color: #373e49;
  border-left: 2px solid #434a54;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>Welcome</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <div id="username">
      <div id="usernameIcon">
        <img src="IMAGES/UsernameIcon.svg" class="usernameIcon">
      </div>
      <div id="usernameTextbox">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="tbUsername" placeholder="Username">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="password">

    </div>
    <div id="btnLogin">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a `padding-top:1px` in your `#content`

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #222222;
}
#header {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  width: 60%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #303640;
  margin-left: 20%;
  padding-top:1px /* NEW */
}
#username {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #373e49;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #373e49;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#usernameIcon {
  width: 12%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.usernameIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#usernameTextbox {
  width: 88%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.tbUsername {
  background-color: #373e49;
  border-left: 2px solid #434a54;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>Welcome</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <div id="username">
      <div id="usernameIcon">
        <img src="IMAGES/UsernameIcon.svg" class="usernameIcon">
      </div>
      <div id="usernameTextbox">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="tbUsername" placeholder="Username">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="password">

    </div>
    <div id="btnLogin">

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, like I said simplest fix ever. Thank you for helping me here.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `position` to `absolute`. That´s simple, put it on the element that has the `margin-top:10%;` you´ll see it works!